# Network traffic (data usage) monitor for Windows 10

Tags: windows, security, network-monitoring, traffic, network-traffic

I want to see and analyze which processes (and and if possible, browser tabs) has used what amount of traffic.

I am on Windows 10 and have the Network Meter gadget installed (relic of Windows 7), and it currently says uploaded data is 280MB. I'd like to install a monitor which will let me know where this 280MB has gone as I do not know if I've been infected by a virus (windows defender says I'm ok), or if Windows 10 is uploading information, or if someone on my network just copied a file off my computer (despite me not sharing anything).

I do have Google Drive and OneDrive installed, but have not placed any files in either drive for the day.

I understand that it's probably impossible to figure out where this traffic came from, but would like a monitoring software which will tell me this for the future.

I currently have GlassWire installed, but not sure if there is a better tool out there.